# Core data model with relationships

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have been working on my Core Data model for my application. I believe my final model is correct, but there are a few things I am a bit confused on. This is what I would like to do:

1. User creates a name for a deck of cards.
2. User is then brought to another input screen where they would input a question and answer to be saved under the previous name they created.
3. Both question and answer would stay linked to each other, as well as stay linked to their name. (There can also be more than one question and answer pair per deck)

What i have done is this:

[image: Core data model]

From what I have read [in this guide](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-and-swift-relationships-and-more-fetching--cms-25070), it seems I do not need a separate entity for the question and answer. It seems I can just create those two relationships under the Name entity. So I am not quite sure whether I should just create a question and answer relationship under the Name entity, or have separate entities for both questions and answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first entity is a deck of questions, you should probably call it `Deck` instead of `Name`

Your second entity name should be singular, since each entity represents a single `Card` object.

Since each card has one question and answer, you don't have to model that using separate `Question` and `Answer` entities.  Simply store each card's answer with its question.

[image]

As for why you store your questions and answers in a separate entity, it's the only efficient way to model a one-to-many relationship, where each deck has many cards (or questions).

Otherwise, there'd be no intuitive way to represent a (fixed or) variable number of questions and answer attributes within the deck itself.  At worst, your `Deck` would end up looking like:

```
extension Deck {
    @NSManaged var name: String
    @NSManaged var question1: String
    @NSManaged var answer1: String
    @NSManaged var question2: String
    @NSManaged var answer2: String
    @NSManaged var question3: String
    @NSManaged var answer3: String
    @NSManaged var question4: String
    @NSManaged var answer4: String
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @petah for the great answer. This is going to help me a lot. Can i safely make these drastic changes to my model without having to start a new project? Just make my changes, delete my NSManagedObject subclasses and generate new ones?

Comment: Yes.  No need to start a new project.